# Which application to draw symbols?

Tags: windows, graphics

I have little graphics experience, and need to build symbols that look like this:

[image]

ie. a main rectangle with little circles that can be either filled with a single color or split in 1-4 colors.

Which Windows application could I use for this, preferable free/open-source? Again, I'm no graphics guy, so ideally, the application should be dead-easy to use.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to fail the "dead easy" test because it is a very powerful comprehensive program but in the interest of building a complete list of good answers let me mention my favorite [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/).  I do a few relatively simple things using the basic tools, but it does take some poking around to get used to.

Answer (score 0):

For simple graphic editing I've used [The GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) quite a bit.  It can do some pretty hefty editing, but I mainly use it for cropping images (because MSPaint is no way to live).

Answer (score 0):

For symbols [DIA](http://live.gnome.org/Dia) is worth a look as it can export to a lot of vector formats.

Answer (score 0):

Inkscape, as Dennis says, or [paint.net](http://www.getpaint.net/) for bitmap (not vector) editing.